# Number of $l$-tuples $(A_1, A_2,\cdots, A_l)$ such that $∅ ⊆ A_1 ⊆ A_2 ⊆ · · · ⊆ A_l ⊆ S$.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $l$ and $n$ be positive integers and let $S$ be a set with $n$ elements. Find the number of $l$-tuples $(A_1, A_2,\cdots, A_l)$ such that $∅ ⊆ A_1 ⊆ A_2 ⊆ · · · ⊆ A_l ⊆ S$.

---

I haven't tried anything on this problem because I'm completely stuck. Can someone give me a hint.

Thanks

Comment: Usually in mathematics, it is good to start with small numbers. Try to solve it for $l=1$ and then $l=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can consider $n$ boxes (elements) and assign to each box a number $m$ between $1$ and $l+1$ ($l+1$ possibilities) that represents "the first $A_m$ to which that box belongs" (where $A_{l+1}=S$).

Equivalently, if you have a partition of the set $\{1,...,n\}$, how can you make a tuple by joining the elements of the partition? How many ways can you do it?

Comment: I got it! Thanks